# Python, split array by gradient of dataset

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm novice when it comes to programming of any sort.

I have a set of x and y values.

```
x = [1.3, 2.1, 3.5, 4.0, 3.9, 3.1, 2.7, 1.5, 1.7, 2.0, 3.6, 4.2]
y = [1.0, 1.4, 2.0, 2.2, 2.7, 3.1, 3.3, 3.9, 4.3, 4.4, 5.0, 5.5]
```

I want to separate them every time the gradient of x changes sign. My first idea was this

```
import numpy as np

x_grad = np.gradient(x)
array = np.column_stack((x, y, x_grad))

pos = (x_grad >= 0)
neg = (x_grad < 0)
x_y_pos = np.column_stack((x, y, pos))
x_y_neg = np.column_stack((x, y, neg))
x_y_pos_new = x_y_pos[x_y_pos.all(1)]
x_y_neg_new = x_y_neg[x_y_neg.all(1)]
```

but this just gives me two arrays, one when x has a positive gradient and the other when its negative. Which is no good because I need the first and final sections separated as well.

I'm trying to come up with some kind of loop but I can't figure out how to do it, this is my useless attempt

```
array_1=[]

for i in xrange(0, len(array)):
    while True: 
        array[:,2][i] >= 0
        array_1.append(array)
        break
```

Which just gave me the full array 12 times (ie the length of the array). I was hoping it stop when the third column was no longer positive. Even if it did what I wanted I would have still only received the first section.

Just a side note: I can't split it up manually. This is just a simplified example of what happens in many large data files I have, so the gradient shifts happen in different places.  I need to do this for what I want to do with the data.

Any ideas would be much appreciated, I'm driving my self insane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you can first use the sign changing algorithm from [How to detect a sign change for elements in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652368/how-to-detect-a-sign-change-for-elements-in-a-numpy-array)
to build an array of sign change location:

```
import numpy as np

x = [1.3, 2.1, 3.5, 4.0, 3.9, 3.1, 2.7, 1.5, 1.7, 2.0, 3.6, 4.2]
y = [1.0, 1.4, 2.0, 2.2, 2.7, 3.1, 3.3, 3.9, 4.3, 4.4, 5.0, 5.5]
gradx = np.gradient(x)
asign = np.sign(gradx)
signchange = ((np.roll(asign, 1) - asign) != 0).astype(int)
```

Then you can get the element locations of the sign changes from [How do I get a list of indices of non zero elements in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111412/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-indices-of-non-zero-elements-in-a-list)

```
splitloc = [i for i, e in enumerate(signchange) if e != 0]
```

You can then simply split the array use numpy.split

```
np.split(x,splitloc)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, so you only care for the sign of the gradient -- thus, your `x` values really don't matter at all.

Just calculate the running two-element difference

```
y_diffs = y[1:] - y[:-1]
```

and find the indexes where the sign of consecutive elements changes:

switch_idx = []
   sign = y_diffs[0] > 0
   for idx, val in enumerate(y_diffs[1:]):
         sign_new = y_diffs[idx+1] > 0
         if not sign == sign_new:
              switch_idx.append(sign_new)
         sign_new = sign

However, what you do is just find local extrema. I *heavily* doubt what you're doing is scientifically correct -- your sampling intervals (see `x` values) are non-uniform, and thus you should first interpolate your function using a mathematical model that describes your values best. On that, finding the extrema makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I do want to do a spline interpolation of the data but I don't need to find the extrema.  I tried using `splprep` but with zero smoothing I still have noise in secondary values that I calculate from x and y due to the sampling of the x and y values. This "chicane" feature is only a very small event in a full data file so if I add any smoothing with `splprep` then the "chicane" gets "smoothed" out.  My idea was to apply something like `UnivariateSpline` separately to each section.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you want to split the arrays where corresponding gradient is negative/positive.

you get this using list comprehension

```
 negative_x_based_vals = ([x[p] for p in range(0,len(x_grad)) if x_grad[p] < 0]); # result will be [3.9, 3.1, 2.7, 1.5]
 positive_x_based_vals = ([x[p] for p in range(0,len(x_grad)) if x_grad[p] >= 0]; # result will be [1.3, 2.1, 3.5, 4.0, 1.7, 2.0, 3.6, 4.2])
```

Is that what you wanted? (btw this didn't use numpy)

Comment: Thanks for responding. This isn't really what I wanted, the point was that I wanted a new array every time the x gradient changed, so in the dataset example that I gave it would split into three.